# Image always displays with its actual dimensions in Outlook

Tags: asp.net, html, css, email, outlook

I am sending an asp.net web page in email, all the things is working fine in Gmail, Yahoo and Hotmail, but in Outlook the logo image is displayed with its actual width and height. The custom width and height is not applying. This is the [outlook view](http://screencast.com/t/NXHCiMra2h6E)
 and this is [the gmail view](http://screencast.com/t/0wOumfwZ4vgX.)
here is the markup, the url is assigned from code behind

```
<table border="0" 
       cellpadding="0" 
       cellspacing="0" 
       width="167" 
       style="width: 167px; padding: 3px 0 7px 60px; height: 132px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="width: 127px; height: 104px;">
        <div style="padding-top: 20px;">
          <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" 
                     runat="server" 
                     Width="125" Height="100"  
                     BorderColor="Gray" 
                     BorderStyle="Solid" 
                     BorderWidth="1px" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated markup?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "px" after attribute width and height . I think it's the problem.